# How to move all files from current directory to upper directory?

Tags: linux, mv

How to move all files from current directory to upper directory in linux?

I tried something like `mv *.*`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to retag questions, but may I suggest `[linux] [mv] [cwd] [files]`, or something similar?

Comment: I have retagged this question per Stephan202's request.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251091/139312

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

```
mv * .[^.]* ..
```

or (see below for more info):

```
(shopt -s dotglob; mv -- * ..)
```

Explanation: the [`mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) command moves files and directories. The last argument to `mv` is the target (in this case the directory one step "up" in the tree, `..`). The arguments before that are the source files and directories. The asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard which matches all files which do not start with a dot. Files that start with a dot (dotfiles) are "hidden". They are matched using the pattern `.[^.]*` (see edit below).

See the manpage which I linked for more information on `mv`.

---

#### Why `.[^.]*` instead of `.*` ?

As [Chris Johnsen](https://superuser.com/users/14827/chris-johnsen) correctly points out: the pattern `.*` also matches `.` and `..`. Since you don't want to (and cannot) move those, it's better to use a pattern which matches any filename starting with a dot *except those two*. The pattern `.[^.]*` does just that: it matches any filename (1) starting with a dot (2) followed by a character which is *not* a dot (3) followed by zero or more arbitrary characters.

As [Paggas](https://superuser.com/users/15830/paggas) [points out](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory/62192#62192), we'd also have to add the pattern `.??*` in order to match files starting with two dots. See his answer for an alternative solution using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Arjan's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory/62213#62213) mentions [`shopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shopt) in order to avoid all those issues with dotfiles. But then there is still the problem with files starting with a dash. And it requires three commands. Still, I like the idea. I propose to use it like this:

```
(shopt -s dotglob; mv -- * ..)
```

This executes `shopt` in a subshell (thus no second call to `shopt` required) and uses `--` so that files starting with a dash will not be interpreted as arguments to `mv`.

Comment: Using `.*` might cause *mv* to produce warnings/errors about not being able to move `.` and `..`. You might try `mv * .[^.]* ..` instead.

Comment: @alain: you're welcome, and welcome to the site! (If (and only if) one of the posts here sufficiently answered your question, then you can mark it as such. That will get the poster 15 extra reputation points, and also give you 2 rep extra.)

Comment: I really like the shopt solution running in a subshell :)

Comment: There is no harm in the * .* syntax -- including .. is only hazardous when used with chmod and chown and the "recurse" flag, ie chmod -R or chown -R.  And in those cases, don't ever *ever* type chown .* or chmod .* -- chown the top directory in the path you're looking for and use -h (don't follow symbolic links).  But, mv .. simply doesn't do anything so don't worry about it.

Comment: This fails to copy any directories which already exist and are non-empty in the destination. 'mv -f' doesn't help. I don't think there's any way to force this, so  I suspect I have to start by iterating over the files being copied and 'rm' them from the destination. If I'm doing that, then I may as well 'mv' the files one at a time while iterating too.

Comment: Gives mv: rename .[^.]* to ../.[^.]*: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the .[^.]* work on /bin/sh?

Comment: What if you are in the target directory? I used this and it worked: `mv subdir/(*|.[^.]*) .`. Any comments about that?

Comment: didn't work for me ,"mv: cannot stat `.[^.]*`: no such file or directory" ? centos6

Comment: The correct three patterns are `*`, `.[^.]*` and `..?*`. The second maybe  `.[!.]*` for older (POSIX) shells. [Also read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2910105/2350426)

Answer (score 48):

Short answer: use

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t.. -- {} +
```

Long answer:

The command

```
mv * .* ..
```

will not work since `.*` can match `.` and `..`. But the command

```
mv * .[^.]* ..
```

will also not work, since `.[^.]*` won't match, e.g., `..filename`! Instead, what I do is

```
mv * .[^.] .??* ..
```

which will match everything except `.` and `..`. `*` will match everything that doesn't start with a `.`, `.[^.]` will match all 2 character filenames starting with a dot except `..`, and `.??*` will match all filenames starting with a dot with at least 3 characters.

Better yet, you can use

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t.. -- {} +
```

which avoids the ugly glob hacks in `mv * .[^.] .??* ..`!

Comment: Also, I forgot to note the importance of -- so that the command works correctly with file names starting with a dash. I have included -- in my find answer though. A more complete answer using globs is "mv -- * .[^.] .??* ..".

Comment: +1: I came back to add `..?*` to my comment, and you had already taken care of it.

Comment: What can possibly be wrong with trying to mv .. ?  It simply does nothing and can't do anything.  There are other commands where it *can* do something (chmod and chown) but mv and rm simply don't do anything to . or ..

Comment: This did not work with .git/ folder ;(

Comment: This gives mv: illegal option -- t

Comment: Could you explain what the `-- {} +` does? Or where I can find an answer to that question? That is the only magic left for me in this answer.

Comment: Bono, the double dashes tells `mv` to stop looking for any further command options. The braces are a resulting filename. The plus sign says instead of running exec per result (ie. per filename), put as many results in a single exec as possible. For completeness, `-t..` is telling move the target destination to move all of these files to.

Answer (score 14):

Just for the sake of completeness, one can also tell the Bash shell to include hidden files, using [`shopt`](http://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html):

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv -- * ..
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: +1. Much cleaner. I think a slight improvement is in order, though. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The mv lacks the functionality of moving hidden files when using `*` - so why not use copy instead?

```
cp -rf . ..

rm -rf *
```

No need to get into complex solutions of dotglobbing and using find commands.

Comment: __Warning__ If you are moving in the __same filesystem__,  in the biggest part of the cases you didn't really copy the files but only update the directory entries without moving inode or file contenents. See even [[1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48090/66388)]. With a `cp` and `rm` instead you are really copying all.

Answer (score 7):

```
rsync -a --remove-source-files . ..
```

[`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) is an extremely powerful file copying tool, generally used for performing efficient incremental remote backups and mirrors.

With the above command, we are telling `rsync` to copy the content of `.` into `..`

The switch `-a` enables recursion into `.` subdirectories and enables some other common options.

The switch `--remove-source-files` tells rsync to remove the source files after a successful copy, i.e. it makes rsync behave similarly to the `mv` command.

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.

Comment: Sure, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Note that `--remove-source-files` will not remove (synchronized) directories.

Comment: Nice, accepted solution gives me `-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long` error. This one works like the charm.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately trying `mv .` will fail because mv won't be able to unlink the directory that you are currently in.  You could `mv * ..` to move the files in the cwd.

Answer (score 2):

```
mv * .??* ../.
```

`*` gets all not-dot files. `.??*` gets all . files at least three bytes long, which works for all legit ones. Anything left you probably want to `rm` rather than `mv` anyway.

The `../.` doesn't offer any direct benefits over `..` but when doing a move-to-directory it is a very good habit to get into, because it will fail, as you want, if there is something wrong with the path. For example, `mv xyz bletch`, where you *think* `bletch` is a directory, can be made more certain with `mv xyz bletch/.`.

Comment: You might add `.[^.]` to get cover files like `.a`.

Comment: There is no difference between ../ and ../. so I wouldn't bother typing the . after the slash.  Also, in the case of mv and rm, it does no harm to include . and .. in the list, ie there isn't anything scary or wrong with mv * .* /path/to/file/, just as rm . or even -rf . doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This minimized command works on most modern shells:

```
\mv -- {,.{[^.],??}}* ..
```

Otherwise mentioned is a portable solution:

```
\mv -- * .[^.] .??* ..
```

**Features:**

1. \ prevents aliases from altering mv undesirably.
2. -- prevents filenames containing leading hyphens (-xyz) from being interpreted as command-line arguments.
3. .[^.] matches all two character filenames beginning with . except ..
4. .??* matches all other filenames three characters or longer.

**Naive Implementations:**

1. The following skips hidden UNIX filenames, those that begin with . (.bashrc).

   ```
   mv * ..
   ```
2. The following matches .. which recursively attempts to move every directory eventually all the way back to / into .. of the current working directory ($PWD or pwd).  **Never use.**

   ```
   mv .* ..
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It's more correct to use the pattern `* .[!.] .??*` than `* .[^.] .??*` since the former will also work with older shells such as ksh88:

```
mv -- * .[!.] .??* ..
```

- `--` prevents problems when you have a file name which begins with `-`
- `*` matches all file names which don't begin with a `.`
- there are no one character file names which begin with a `.` which you can/should move
- `.[!.]` matches all two character file names which begin with a `.`
- `.??*` matches all three character file names (or longer) which begin with a `.`

With ksh88, the file name pattern `.[^.]` will in fact match the file names `..` (which always exists) and `.^` (which probably doesn't exist), having an effect opposite to what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Find and grep work too.  This kind of structure might be helpful if you wanted to select files on more complicated criteria by modifying find and egrep.

```
find -maxdepth 1 | egrep '^./.'         # Returns all files

mv `find -maxdepth 1 | egrep '^./.'` .. # mv <all files> ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for moving all files to its parent dir. would be

```
mv "`ls`" ../
```

or,
If there are hidden files/directories

use:

```
mv "`ls -a`" ../ 2>/dev/null
```

Also, lets say you want to move the contents of some folder to one of its internal folder tony(say)

use:

```
mv "`ls -a`" /tony 2>/dev/null
```

**Note:**

```
"`ls -a`"
```

To move the files that have spaces in it.

```
2>/dev/null
```

Is for suppressing the warning/error because `ls -a` would print the `.` and `..` folder as well and you can't move or copy them. So for those folders it will show error (if we don't use 2>/dev/null) that it can't move them and the rest will be moved quite comfortably.

Best to avoid `ls -a` if there is no hidden files and just use `ls`.

Comment: Have you tried what will happen when you run `mv $(ls -a)`? That'd tap on the current directory and the directory below it, because `ls -a` will output `..` as well.

Comment: Thanks , @SamiLaine for the suggestion I have made the corrections.
But `mv ls -a ../` would have also worked as per need, Yes it will show those errors as I mentioned above but other than that it will move the required folders/files to the parent dir.

Comment: This won't work for files with spaces.

Comment: @kenorb you need to double quote the `ls` command in order to move files with spaces. I have made the required changes. Thanks for pointing out.