# Move all files from subdirectories to current directory?

Tags: bash, mv, folder-redirection

How can I move the files contained in all subdirectories to the current directory, and then remove the empty subdirectories?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory), but adapting the answer to:

```
mv * .
```

did not work; I received a lot of warnings looking like:

```
mv: wil and ./wil are identical
```

The files contained in the subdirectories have unique names.

Answer (score 50):

You can also use the `-mindepth` option:

```
find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv -i -- {} . \;
```

(Together with `-maxdepth` you could also limit the hierarchy levels from which to collect the files.)

I used `mv -i` (“interactive”) to make `mv` ask before overwriting files.  With a lot of subdirectories, there may be name clashes you'd like to be warned about.

The `--` option stops option processing, so `mv` doesn't get confused by filenames starting with a hyphen.

Clean up the whole bunch of empty subdirectories with

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: Is there also a way to skip the question for overwriting the files by not overwrting them?

Comment: Options for mv: `-n, --no-clobber`: do not overwrite an existing file. You might be interested in `-b, --backup`, too.

Comment: Use `find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv -- {} . \;` if you don't care about files which are overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

```
mv */* .
```

It will move all files from all subdirectories to current directory.

If you need some cleanup, you could use

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

It will delete all empty subdirectories.

Comment: This will only go one directory deep on Mac OS.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
find ./*/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -J % mv % .
```

More Info: Try the find-stamement alone, it should give you a list with all the files you want to move (leave out the `-print0`). Example:

```
probe:test trurl$ find ./*/* -type f
./test_s/test_s_s/testf4
./test_s/test_s_s/testf5
./test_s/testf1
./test_s/testf2
./test_s/testf3
./test_s2/testf6
./test_s2/testf7
```

with `-print0` and `xargs` you are now creating a list of statements to be executed. The `-J %` flag means, insert the list element here, so `mv $FILE .` is executed for every file found.

The above is working for the BSD xargs. If you're using the GNU-version (Linux) take `-I %` instead of `-J %`

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && mv "$file" .; done
```

Answer (score -2):

1 quick trick, only works if your files have extensions (with a dot):

```
mv *.* subdir/
mv .* subdir/
```

Answer (score -2):

Just run this command:-)

`mv **/*.* .`

Comment: That won't find files that don't have a `.` in their name, will it?