# Remove middle folder?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, unix, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux: How to move all files from current directory to upper directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory)

I have foo/bar/myfiles and I want foo/myfiles.

I was trying to git clone a repo into foo, but it made the name of the repo as a folder and put the files in there. I'm thinking of just cloning into the same directory as foo and then renaming it, but I'd rather find a solution to this problem.

I'm working on my server, so a solution for linux would be nice, but I do this a lot on my local machine, so if there's something that can be done for Windows as well, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: To clarify, are `myfiles` some files, or is that a folder?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to go about this, such as:

```
mv foo foo2
mv foo2/bar foo
rm -rf foo2
```

(assuming `foo` is empty save for the folder `bar`)

Edited for errors pointed out by slhck

You can also tell it where to clone the repository in the future:

```
git clone git://repo/bar.git foo
```

Comment: Only if `myfiles` is a folder. If the OP cloned a Git repo into `bar`, then obviously, this won't work. The question's ambiguous in that respect though, since the title talks about "middle" folder, while `myfiles` would be an indication of … well, some files. In that case, you'd have to make sure to move Git's hidden files as well.